# VBA command in Excel to find & delete

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I'm trying to create a macro/VBA to use the value in a certain cell in the find tool. Then search for that value in a different sheet then delete the whole row.

e.g.

```
ABC | DEF 
---------
```

I would like to find the value "ABC" (from sheet 1) in sheet 2 and select the whole row to delete it. The value might be different next time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the value from Sheet1 cell A3 and look for it on Sheet2 and delete the row.

```
Private Sub findAndDelete()

    Dim wordToSearch As String
    Dim rowToDelete As Integer

    'Get word to look for from cell A3
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    wordToSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value

    'Find that word on Sheet2 and delete it
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=wordToSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    rowToDelete = ActiveCell.Row
    Rows(rowToDelete & ":" & rowToDelete).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```